# Nodejs break out of loop with async/bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, loops

So, I've got the following code that works, but I'd like for it to not use a for-loop anymore.

The important bit is the "break" story.

```
    for (const obj of objects) {
        let found = false;

        for (const item of items) {
            const result = item.get(obj);
            if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            notDefined.push(obj);
        }
    }
```

I've tried it with Bluebird but I'm failing there. Array.prototype.forEach isn't an option, it cannot be stopped.

What else can I try?

EDIT: The point is filling that list of objects, the "notDefined" one. The list represents items not found in a map that has been filled purposefully.

So a bunch of them are tested for a match.

If the item **does** get found, we should skip to the next group. And of course: stop looping over the items because we've found a match and so there's no point in continuing. No need to keep checking all the remaining items, which may well be several hundred thousands.

EDIT2: The purpose of that "notDefined" list is to write the objects to a text file, that can later be checked manually.

The variable names have been changed away from their originals, as to have something different on here.

The purpose of the code is comparing the contents of several directories on one machine, to the content on several directories on an other machine.

This data comes in as several CSV files. They are all read and a list is generated per CSV file. The data in this CSV file is:

- Absolute file path
- File size
- Md5

And some other metadata.

However, this list each time does not contain merely the strings of the absolute file path, it contains a `Map()`, the key being a combination of the 3 mentioned pieces of data, just above.

So we have several CSV files for machine A, and then several CSVs for machine B. And we wish to see if items found on machine A, can also be found on machine B.

That's what I'm trying to do here: loop over all the CSVs and find matching items.

If I find a match, then there's no point to continue checking and I can skip to the next set. That's where the `break;` comes from.

But I do need to check for every single match and then write a result for all items not found anywhere.

Comment: Instead of wanting to "not use a loop anymore", what do you need to actually do? Because using promises (which is unlikely to require bluebird anymore, that was a library that made sense back when browsers and node didn't natively support them). The code you're showing is very curious in that it seems to not care about what it finds, just that "some property" is in "any object", which without further explanation feels almost useless: can you describe what you're concretely trying to do, because there might be a really simple way to do that that you haven't considered.

Comment: Where is the async code here?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Added some more explanation.

Comment: @VLAZ async/await is a possible solution. It's not in there yet, nor do I recall having written so.

Comment: I'm not talking about the keyword `await` - which part of this code is asynchronous? You mention that you've tried it with Bluebird but you've tried *what* with Bluebird? Which part of this code needs to be handled as asynchronous?

Comment: @VLAZ The inner for loop. But I can't find a way to stop the loop over the items once I run into the condition where it has to stop.

Comment: But that's a synchronous loop - why does it need to be handled asynchronously?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily. It was just a thought. The only real thing I'm looking to achieve is that it no longer uses a for-loop.

Comment: The edit's not super clear: you have two lists, one called `objects` (protip: name this better, what _kind_ of objects?) and one called `items` (same tip), then for each object, you check if they're referenced by any item? If so, you might be pleased to learn that [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) exists (along with other functions you've probably not heard of before: array.includes, array.every, and array.find are all powerful functions, give the list of modern array functions a read over).

Comment: Having said that, you're basically running O(n²) here and that's going to kill your performance quite a bit - so what are you concretely doing? (i.e. what is the _purpose_ of generating that `notDefined` list? What is it for? Because we might be able to do _that_ without doing any of the code you're showing)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans More explanation added, as requested.

Comment: I would 100% not do this in code, but instead put that CVS data into a Sqlite3 (or "real", but no real reason to) db instead, and have _that_ do the work for you because it's far better at data analysis like "finding shared and missing things". That's literally its reason to exist =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you have two Arrays, `objects` and `items`.

And, it looks to me like you want a decently-performing way to know whether each object is *missing* from all your Maps.  I guess your interest in breaking out of a for-loop is part of your strategy to make this perform decently.

May I suggest another approach?  Let's start by making a single Set of all the keys in all your Map objects.  Something like this.

```
const allKeys = new Set()
for (const item of items)
  for (const key of item.keys())
    allKeys.add(key)
```

Now you run through your array of objects, one by one, and push them into `notDefined` if they're absent from the `allKeys` set.

```
for (const obj of objects)
  if (!allKeys.has(obj)) 
    notDefined.push(obj)
```

This gets you out of nested iterations on two arrays. And it performs well because Set lookups are fast.

All together, in some perfectly synchronous tight loops (no Promises needed):

```
const allKeys = new Set()
for (const item of items)
  for (const key of item.keys())
    allKeys.add(key)

for (const obj of objects)
  if (!allKeys.has(obj))
     notDefined.push(obj)
```

To make it even faster, you could consider building your `allKeys` set as you read your raw data from your CSV files. That would save the pass over all the elements of `items`.